# org.json.JSONException: Value Connection of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to login and it is giving me `JSONExceptionError`. Below is my login code. If I put `localhost` in my php code it works, but for this IP address its not working.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

TextView textView;
Button login_button;
EditText Username,Password;
String username,password;
String login_url = "http://192.168.0.21/maps/login.php";
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.reg_txt);
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Register.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    login_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bn_login);
    Username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.login_name);
    Password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.login_password);
    login_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             username = Username.getText().toString();
             password = Password.getText().toString();
            if(username.equals("")||password.equals("")){
                builder.setTitle("Something went wrong");
                displayAlert("Enter a valid username and password");
            }
            else{
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, login_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                            String code = jsonObject.getString("code");
                            if(code.equals("login_failed")){
                                builder.setTitle("Error in login");
                                displayAlert(jsonObject.getString("message"));
                            }
                            else{
                                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MapsActivity.class));
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }){
                  @Override
                  protected Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
                      Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                      params.put("user_name",username);
                      params.put("password",password);
                    return params;
                  }
                };
                MySingeleton.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestque(stringRequest);
            }
        }
    });
}
public void displayAlert(String message){
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Username.setText("");
            Password.setText("");
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
}
```

Below is my php connection code. After running in browser it is giving the output but data is not getting inserted into the database.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$host = "";
$user_name = "android";
$user_password = "^AndroidReg2019";
$db_name = "mapdb";

$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user_name,$user_password,$db_name);

if($conn)
echo "Connection success..";
else
echo "Connection failed...";
?>
```

Below is my login php code.

```
<?php
require "init.php";
$user_name = $_POST["user_name"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$sql = "select user_name from user_info where user_name = '$user_name' and password = '$password';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$response = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$name  = $row[0];
$code = "login_success";
array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"user_name"=>$user_name));
echo json_encode($response);
}
else{
$code = "login_failed";
$message = "Please verify credentials and try login again.";
array_push($response,array("code"=>$code,"message"=>$message));
echo json_encode($response);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Is the link http://192.168.0.21/maps/login.php working in POSTMAN/ any other REST services tool?

Comment: yes. its working.

Comment: Can you send me the Json you are sending it to the link?

Comment: No i meant the values you are sending via post

Comment: name=a&email=a&user_name=a&password=a

Comment: You are parsing name in the param you have mentioned in the code. You are parsing only  params.put("user_name",username);
                      params.put("password",password);

Comment: ok i sent that for register and not for login. i will change it and send u

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); Whst is $conn here? just check if your connection is proper in SQL

Comment: in postman the output for the values of username and password is this. Connection success..
[
    {
        "code": "login_success",
        "user_name": null
    }
] but if i try to do the same in android its not showing any message and it is not logging in too

Comment: yes the connection is fine. it works iwth localhost but not with this.

Comment: Okay last option try to put localhost in $host = ""; means $host = "localhost"

Comment: its working fine now. thanks

Comment: but it wont work if i give any other ip address rather than localhost and "" this

Comment: That is because your SQL is connected to local host of the server, If you host your SQL to some other server you can change the local host to the server name. That is how it behaves. Any ways if you are happy with the answer please upvote anc accept my answer below

Comment: i upvoted it. but the thing is this. Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are few of my observations below

- You are parsing name in the param you have mentioned in the code
- You are parsing only

> params.put("user_name",username);
>       params.put("password",password);

- Also try to trim your username and password to make sure you are not parsing unnecessary spaces in between
- last option try to put localhost in $host = ""; means $host = "localhost"

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in these line

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0)
```

Your data is already a JSONObject. No need to convert response to Array and get Object.

Simple do this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
```

Comment: You answer is spot on, But the problems what she is facing is connection to her SQL, Some what PHP connection issue with MYSQL